# Potential Duplicates Detection, with 3 Severity Level

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates

I wanna make a program that detect a potential duplicates with 3 severity level.
let consider my data is only in two column, but with thousands row. 
data in second column delimited only with comma. data example :

```
Number | Material
1      | helmet,valros,42
2      | helmet,iron,knight
3      | valros,helmet,42
4      | knight,helmet
5      | valros,helmet,42
6      | plain,helmet
7      | helmet, leather
```

and my 3 levels is :

**very high :** A,B,C **vs** A,B,C

**high :** A,B,C **vs** B,C,A

**so so :** A,B,C **vs** A,B

so far i just can make the first level, i don't know how to do the 2nd and the 3rd level.

what I've tried.

```
Sub duplicates_separation()

    Dim duplicate(), i As Long
    Dim delrange As Range, cell As Long
    Dim shtIn As Worksheet, shtOut As Worksheet



     Set shtIn = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("input")
    Set shtOut = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("output")

    x = 2
    y = 1

    Set delrange = shtIn.Range("b1:b10000")  'set your range here

   ReDim duplicate(0)
'search duplicates in 2nd column
    For cell = 1 To delrange.Cells.Count
        If Application.CountIf(delrange, delrange(cell)) > 1 Then
            ReDim Preserve duplicate(i)
            duplicate(i) = delrange(cell).Address
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next


        'print duplicates
    For i = UBound(duplicate) To LBound(duplicate) Step -1
    shtOut.Cells(x, 1).EntireRow.Value = shtIn.Range(duplicate(i)).EntireRow.Value


End Sub
```

duplicates detected by the program :

```
3      | valros,helmet,42
 5      | valros,helmet,42
```

what i expected:

```
Number | Material
1      | helmet,valros,42
3      | valros,helmet,42
5      | valros,helmet,42
4      | knight,helmet
2      | helmet,iron,knight
```

i have an idea for detecting duplicates lv 2, but I think it will be so complicated and make the program slow.

1. turn column 2 to columns with "text to columns" command
2. sort column from A to Z (alphabetically)
3. concatenate the column
4. do countif like done in detecting duplicates lv 1

is there a way to detect the 2nd & 3rd level duplicates?

---

UPDATE

Yesterday I went to friend's house to consult about this problem, but his solution is in JAVA languange.. >which i don't understand

```
public class ali {

    static void sPrint(String[] Printed) {
        for (int iC = 0; iC < Printed.length; iC++) {
            System.out.print(String.valueOf(Printed[iC]) + " | ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String Args[]) {
        int defaultLength = 10;
        int indexID = 0;
        int indexDesc = 1;
        String[] DETECTORP1 = new String[defaultLength];
        String[] DETECTORP2 = new String[defaultLength];
        String[] DETECTORP3 = new String[defaultLength];
        String[] DETECTORP4 = new String[defaultLength];
        String[][] theString = new String[5][2];
        theString[0] = new String[]{"1", "A, B, C, D"};
        theString[1] = new String[]{"2", "A, B, C, D"};
        theString[2] = new String[]{"3", "A, B, C, D, E"};
        theString[3] = new String[]{"4", "A, B, D, C, E"};
        theString[4] = new String[]{"5", "A, B, D, C, E, F"};
        int P1 = 0;
        int P2 = 0;
        int P3 = 0;
        int P4 = 0;
        for (int iC = 0; iC < theString.length; iC++) {
            System.out.println(theString[iC][indexID] + " -> " + theString[iC][indexDesc]);
        }
        for (int iC = 0; iC < theString.length; iC++) {
            int LEX;
            String theReference[] = theString[iC][indexDesc].replace(",", ";;").split(";;");
            for (int iD = 0; iD < theString.length; iD++) {
                if (iC != iD) {
                    String theCompare[] = theString[iD][1].replace(",", ";;").split(";;");
                    if (theReference.length == theCompare.length) {
                        LEX=0;
                        int theLength = theReference.length;
                        for (int iE = 0; iE < theLength; iE++) {
                            if (theReference[iE].equals(theCompare[iE])) {
                                LEX += 1;
                            }
                        }
                        if (LEX == theLength) {
                            DETECTORP1[P1] = theString[iC][indexID] + " WITH " + theString[iD][indexID];
                            P1 += 1;
                        } else {
                            LEX = 0;
                            for (int iF = 0; iF < theReference.length; iF++) {
                                for (int iG = 0; iG < theCompare.length; iG++) {
                                    if (theReference[iF].equals(theCompare[iG])) {
                                        LEX += 1;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            if (LEX == theReference.length) {
                                DETECTORP2[P2] = theString[iC][indexID] + " WITH " + theString[iD][indexID];
                                P2 += 1;
                            }

                        }

                    } else {
                        LEX = 0;
                        if (theReference.length > theCompare.length) {
                            for (int iF = 0; iF < theReference.length; iF++) {
                                for (int iG = 0; iG < theCompare.length; iG++) {
                                    if (iG == iF) {
                                        if (theReference[iF].equals(theCompare[iF])) {
                                            LEX += 1;
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            if (LEX <= theReference.length && LEX >= theCompare.length) {
                                DETECTORP3[P3] = theString[iC][indexID] + " WITH " + theString[iD][indexID];
                                P3 += 1;
                            }
                        } else {
                            LEX =0;
                            for (int iF = 0; iF < theCompare.length; iF++) {
                                for (int iG = 0; iG < theReference.length; iG++) {
                                    if (iG == iF) {
                                        if (theCompare[iF].equals(theReference[iF])) {
                                            LEX += 1;
                                        //    System.out.println(theReference[iG] + "==" + theCompare[iG]);
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            if (LEX <= theCompare.length && LEX >= theReference.length) {
                                DETECTORP3[P3] = theString[iC][indexID] + " WITH " + theString[iD][indexID];
                                P3 += 1;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }

            }

        }
        sPrint(DETECTORP1);
        sPrint(DETECTORP2);
        sPrint(DETECTORP3);
    }
}
```

how to do this in VBA?

Comment: This may inspire one way forward: [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

Comment: it's inspiring, do you know how to do it in VBA?

Comment: Well, have you looked at the Wikipedia article? There are two example implementations right in there. Just translate into VBA.

Comment: I only know VBA, hehe. but I'll try.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243036/levenshtein-distance-in-excel found this!

Comment: @jean, i think levenshtein distance approach just too much. i don't want to calculate similarity per character. just per words which delimited with comma

Comment: I think levenshtein distane is an overkill in this simple situation.  @AlfaBachtiar - why dont you write an algorithm that sorts your delimited text it's would be less complicated to write the comparison method afterwards. The other option is to give each text a value and sum up the values in each cell. As simple as same (sum)/value would mean duplicate values.

Comment: @mehow, i have tried to sort my delimited text, and do countif. but that only solve the lv2 severity..

Comment: I'll update my severity lv2 code.

Answer (score 1):

Really, it depends how you want to define "severity level". Here's one way to do it, not necessarily the best: Use the Levensthein distance.

Represent each of your items by a one-character attribute symbol, e.g.

```
H    helmet
K    knight
I    iron
$    Leather
^    Valros
╔    Plain
¢    Whatever
etc.
```

Then convert your Material lists into a string containing sequence of characters representing these attributes:

```
HIK = helmet,iron,knight
¢H  = plain,helmet
```

Then compute the Levenshtein distance between those two strings. That will be your "severity level".

```
Debug.Print LevenshteinDistance("HIK","¢H")
'returns 3
```

Two implementations of the Levenshtein distance are shown in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). And indeed you are in luck: someone on StackOverflow [ported this to VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243036/levenshtein-distance-in-excel).

In the comments section below, you say you don't like having to represent each of your possible attributes by one-character symbols. Fair enough; I agree this is a bit silly. Workaround: It is, in fact, possible to adapt the Levenshtein Distance algorithm to look not at each character in a string, but at each element of an array instead, and do comparisons based on that. I show how to make this change in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21277408/119775) to your follow-up question.

Comment: if there's thousand of attributes in my data, then I must define symbol that represent my data singly?

Comment: and btw, how to do your first step? im really new at this, and i wanna learn.

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) Try something; come back and post a question if you run into any specific problems.

Comment: then, levensthein distance is not a solution for my problem. i've updated the question

Comment: After thinking about this, I'm sure you can adapt the Levensthein distance code so that it is *not* necessary to represent each attribute by one character. If I were in your shoes, that's what I'd try to do.

Comment: should I combine countif and levenshtein distance?

Comment: i look over this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16346451/find-which-cells-have-the-smallest-levenshtein-distance now i just need to figure out how to do it in 50k data

Comment: stil stuck in same position, i just cant figure how i can compare the levenstein distance percentage in this huge data. if there 50 data, there will be 2500 comparison.

Comment: [My answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21277408/119775) to your other question should put you in the right direction. Please consider upvoting/accepting if you think these answers are useful.